# Passing NSMutable array from one view to another

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I want to add an element to a NSMutableArray in one view and that array should reflect in another view.
I am using NSuserDefaults technique for this purpose..

Here's my code:

**View for adding element**

```
- (IBAction)donebutton:(id)sender {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults new];

if ([defaults objectForKey:@"arr"]) {
    self.arrayy = [defaults objectForKey:@"arr"];
}
else {
    self.arrayy = [NSMutableArray new];
}

[self.arrayy addObject:self.titlefield.text];

[defaults setObject:self.arrayy forKey:@"arr"];

[defaults synchronize];

}
```

**View to show all these arrays**

```
//in view did load..//

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults new];

if ([defaults objectForKey:@"arr"]) {
    self.data_array = [defaults objectForKey:@"arr"];
}
else {
    self.data_array = [NSMutableArray new];
}

[defaults synchronize];
```

But here the problem is when app launches I am able to add the element to the array first time,and it is reflecting in the second view too.But second time when I press the done button I am getting an NSException error saying:

> *Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'*

Comment: I would not be using NSUserDefaults to pass data from view to view. If the views have no relationship maintained by them (eg. reference to each other), then at the very least create an intermediary object to hold the data for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an `NSMutableArray`, you have an `NSArray`. Anything you read from `NSUserDefaults` will be immutable.

Change this:

```
self.data_array = [defaults objectForKey:@"arr"];
```

to:

```
self.data_array = [[defaults objectForKey:@"arr"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Hi rmaddy, this was really helpful but in my case it is not working. The problem is the same, infact now even the array also stops updating which was fine before. Any suggestions ?

Comment: ohh,it worked..I also changed self.arrayy = [defaults objectForKey:@"arr"]; to self.arrayy = [[defaults objectForKey:@"arr"] mutableCopy];
Thanks.